# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient :Failed to retreive session ID from broker. Please retry

Tags: azureservicebus, amqp, azure-servicebus-queues

I build a listener following the guide [amqplite as server of servicebus client](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/issues/176)

I can successfully send message to my server but fail to receive message with error:

> Failed to retreive session ID from broker. Please retry.
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionClient.d__37.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionReceivePump.d__21.MoveNext()

The receiver code looks like:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

        public async Task TestAMQP()
        {
            var client = new QueueClient("Endpoint=sb://127.0.0.1/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxx;SharedAccessKey=xxx;TransportType=Amqp",
                 "q1");

            client.RegisterSessionHandler(
               this.NotificationHandler,
               new SessionHandlerOptions(this.ExceptionHandler)
               {
                   ...
               });
         ...
        }

        private Task ExceptionHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs arg)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

And then I get error in this ExceptionHandler.

As the client SDK `Microsoft.AzureWebjobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` is totally a black box for me, I fail to find what happen with this message.

Did I missed some information that server should send back to the client?